# How do I create a serializer for this category model without the product field? DRF

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to create an Apiview for the model category and define an endpoint for only performing a create category field but Products and Category are related to the ForeignKey method. So, I was trying this method but any works yet.
these are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True) 


    class Meta:
    
        ordering = ('name',) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.slug}/' 

class Product(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=99.99)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True)        
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        
        ordering = ('-date_added',) # date create it in descending order

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
```

I create a serializer for the product model,  working only for creating products.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
            view_name='product-detail',
            lookup_field='pk'
    )
    class Meta:

        model = Product
        fields = (
            "category",
            "url", 
            "pk",
            "name",
            "description",
            "price",
            "get_image",
            "get_thumbnail",
            "date_added",
        )
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ( 
            "id",
            "name",
            "get_absolute_url",
            "products",
        )
```

also, I was trying this method that overrides the create method for the related field;

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    products = ProductSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    many=True, queryset=Product.objects.all())
)
    class Meta:
        
        model = Category
        fields = [
            "name",
            "slug",
            "products"
            ]
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        category = Category.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Product.objects.create(category=category, **products_data)
        return Category

    def to_representation(self, category):
        representation = super(CategorySerializer, self).to_representation(category)
        representation['products'] = ProductSerializer(category.product_set.all(), many=True).data
        return representation
```

give me this bug = Category() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'user

I can create categories from the admin site only.

Answer (score 1):

You can set that products is not `required` on your serializer:

serializers.py

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ( 
            "id",
            "name",
            "get_absolute_url",
            "products",
        )
```

If you want to define an `endpoint` for only creating categories then you can go with a simple [`CreateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes):

views.py

```py
class CategoryCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

Register URL, lets say:

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('products/create/', CategoryCreateAPIView.as_view())
]
```

endpoint

```
http://localhost:8000/products/create/
```

### Extra Notes:

1. You can use Django's [`.slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) to auto populate your slug field by overriding the your model `.create` method.
2. In the same way, it is also possible to [create thumbnails](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails) from an uploaded image. So you do not need to upload two files.

Comment: Thanks, did work for the category model, but now, I am having the same problem with productlistcreateapiview. bug = TypeError at /product/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Product.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Product.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ProductSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

Comment: I resolve the issue by eliminating the function for perform create in both apiview, create product and create category, which uses this statement serializer.save(user=self.request.user), I think the bug is in self.request.user.

Comment: That is because the `serializer`does not contain the `request`object. Although you can pass it using [`extra context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).